# how to encrypt third party api key in a website

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I got an api key from yelp. I am still learning how to use this api in my website.
As of now my api key is in java script which is visible to everyone. I am using visual studio for developing this website.

can anyone tell me how to encrypt this api key?

Comment: If you're calling the Yelp API from javascript only, you can't, it will always be visible when viewing the code. You can call your own server instead, and use your server to call the Yelp API, that would make the key invisible to users in some degree, but it does'nt really matter, as the chances of someone stealing your key == null.

Comment: it's not only for yelp api. I want to know how to encrypt any api key in javascript

Comment: You can't really encrypt anything in javascript. It's a wide open language. You can minify, encode and decode in stuff like base64, and do a lot of strange stuff that makes it hard to read, but at the end of the day, you can't really hide anything, as most clever developers will figure it out anyway. The only way to really hide something from the clientside is doing it on the serverside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JCryption **http://www.jcryption.org/**

Cryption is a javascript HTML-Form encryption plugin, which encrypts the POST/GET-Data that will be sent when you submit a form.

Comment: The question is about encrypting a string in a html/js file not about formulars.